# Killing a Haskell binary

Tags: unix, haskell

If I press Ctrl+C, this throws an exception (always in thread 0?). You can catch this if you want - or, more likely, run some cleanup and then rethrow it. But the usual result is to bring the program to a halt, one way or another.

Now suppose I use the Unix `kill` command. As I understand it, `kill` basically sends a (configurable) Unix signal to the specified process.

How does the Haskell RTS respond to this? Is it documented somewhere? I would *imagine* that sending `SIGTERM` would have the same effect as pressing Ctrl+C, but I don't know that for a fact...

(And, of course, you can use `kill` to send signals that have nothing to do with killing at all. Again, I would *imagine* that the RTS would ignore, say, `SIGHUP` or `SIGPWR`, but I don't know for sure.)

Comment: Ctrl-C sends `SIGINT`. I would expect `SIGTERM` to be handled differently to `SIGINT`.

Comment: I think there is a default action for all signals defined by Posix and/or the specific system, see here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html (Scroll down to the table).

Comment: @bennofs Good to know. The default action for `SIGINT` appears to be to terminate the process, yet the RTS clearly handles this specially. It would be nice to know if any other signals receive special handling...

Comment: I think in GHC the bound thread receives the signal and calls a registered handler, which informs each Capability to gracefully terminate. Some relevant code is also in Schedule.c around line 200, grep for "// The interruption / shutdown sequence." (looks like the best documentation in this case is the code itself).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Searching for "signal" in the [ghc source code](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/search?q=signal&ref=cmdform) on github revealed the [installDefaultSignals](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/7cc8a3cc5c2970009b83844ff9cc4e27913b8559/rts/posix/Signals.c#L596) function:

```
void
initDefaultHandlers(void)
{
    struct sigaction action,oact;

    // install the SIGINT handler
    action.sa_handler = shutdown_handler;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &action, &oact) != 0) {
sysErrorBelch("warning: failed to install SIGINT handler");
    }

#if defined(HAVE_SIGINTERRUPT)
    siginterrupt(SIGINT, 1);    // isn't this the default? --SDM
#endif

    // install the SIGFPE handler

    // In addition to handling SIGINT, also handle SIGFPE by ignoring it.
    // Apparently IEEE requires floating-point exceptions to be ignored by
    // default, but alpha-dec-osf3 doesn't seem to do so.

    // Commented out by SDM 2/7/2002: this causes an infinite loop on
    // some architectures when an integer division by zero occurs: we
    // don't recover from the floating point exception, and the
    // program just generates another one immediately.
#if 0
    action.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGFPE, &action, &oact) != 0) {
    sysErrorBelch("warning: failed to install SIGFPE handler");
}
#endif

#ifdef alpha_HOST_ARCH
    ieee_set_fp_control(0);
#endif

    // ignore SIGPIPE; see #1619
    // actually, we use an empty signal handler rather than SIG_IGN,
    // so that SIGPIPE gets reset to its default behaviour on exec.
    action.sa_handler = empty_handler;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGPIPE, &action, &oact) != 0) {
sysErrorBelch("warning: failed to install SIGPIPE handler");
    }

    set_sigtstp_action(rtsTrue);
}
```

From that, you can see that GHC installs at least SIGINT and SIGPIPE handlers. I don't know if there are any other signal handlers hidden in the source code.

Comment: Good work. So it appears that `SIGINT` is the only signal with special treatment...

Answer (score 17):

Googling "haskell catch sigterm" led me to [`System.Posix.Signals`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/2.6.0.1/doc/html/System-Posix-Signals.html) of the `unix` package, which has a rather nice looking system for catching and handling these signals.  Just scroll down to the "Handling Signals" section.

**EDIT:**  A trivial example:

```hs
import System.Posix.Signals
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

termHandler :: MVar () -> Handler
termHandler v = CatchOnce $ do
    putStrLn "Caught SIGTERM"
    putMVar v ()

loop :: MVar () -> IO ()
loop v = do
    putStrLn "Still running"
    threadDelay 1000000
    val <- tryTakeMVar v
    case val of
        Just _ -> putStrLn "Quitting" >> return ()
        Nothing -> loop v

main = do
    v <- newEmptyMVar
    installHandler sigTERM (termHandler v) Nothing
    loop v
```

Notice that I had to use an MVar to inform `loop` that it was time to quit.  I tried using `exitSuccess` from `System.Exit`, but since `termHandler` executes in a thread that isn't the main one, it can't cause the program to exit.  There might be an easier way to do it, but I've never used this module before so I don't know of one.  I tested this on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: This library looks _highly_ relevant if I do indeed need to override the default actions. I'd still like to know what those defaults are though. ;-)

Comment: My mistake.  Looking at the source of that module doesn't tell me much either.  I tried several different signals and it seems that the default action when any of these is sent to that process is to just stop the process.

Comment: No need to apologise; your information certainly looks useful.

Comment: Thank you for this! To add to this:
I see that now the System.Posix.Signals module has `raiseSignal` function, which could be used to re-raise the received signal. And by using `CatchInfo` or `CatchinfoOnce` you can get the needed information to pass to `raiseSignal`. So you could do this instead of using MVar + loop.